# Having trouble with unmute.js and tone.js, not able to get audio playback on mobile

Tags: p5.js, tonejs

Pretty new to programming, although had ChatGPT help me write a p5js script that acts as a music player where users can change stems and create unique mixes of a track.

Here's the code repo I created: https://github.com/Weinbagz/Playerz-Stemz

I was able to use unmutejs to make it so when the user pressed the play button, it unmuted and audio was playing on mobile.

Now I'm not able to get it to work and I'm getting the following error in the console when I press the play button on mobile:

```
p5js says: There's an error as "suspend" could not be called as a function (on line 131 in unmutejs [/unmute.js:131:40]).
Verify whether "context" has "suspend" in it and check the spelling, letter-casing (JavaScript is case-sensitive) and its type.
For more: 
[Log] ▶️ Error at line 131 in "updateContextState" in aa846b18-ef95-4416-8680-c22d6ddd17b7 
[Error] TypeError: context.suspend is not a function. (In 'context.suspend()', 'context suspend' is undefined)
```

Audio playback on mobile was working for a bit, updated some style changes, and now it doesn't work. Not quite sure where to go.